# stm32f103 internal interrupt can not reach the wanted frequency (350ns) (lowest reached is 4us)

Tags: timer, interrupt, stm32, pwm, bluepill

i am trying to generate a PWM signal by turning a GPIO pin high and low using an interrupt generated by TIMER1, why i am doing it this way is a whole different story, so i need to generate an interrupt every 350ns, i calculated prescaler and the ARR for 72MHz and i found out that i need a prescaler of 1 and an ARR of 25 so i set the parameters according to these values, now i have 25 clock cycle to do what i want before the next interrupt triggers, so at each interrupt the specified pin has to change state (High to Low or Low to High), i am looking at the output signal using an oscilloscope and i am stuck with an output of 8us (which means an interrupt every 4 us), how can i fix this? where am i failing? what am i possibly doing wrong?
Here is what i am doing in the interrupt function:

```
void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
    if ((GPIOC->ODR & GPIO_PIN_13) != 0x00u)
    {
        GPIOC-> ODR = 0x0000;
    }
    else
    {
        GPIOC-> ODR = 0x2000;
    }
  }
```

Here is a photo of the output signal :
[Oscilloscope output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKfEA.jpg)

is it possible that the code inside the interrupt exceeds 25 clock cycle? if so how can i do it without exceeding ? thanks

Comment: I am not sure about the STMF103, but TIMER1 of STM32L4xx can directly generate PWM signals without software in the loop, did you investigate this?

Comment: @PaulR you are right, it can, unfortunately what i have in mind is a little different, so i need to toggle the pin as fast as possible to make use of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible that the code inside the interrupt exceeds 25 clock
>   cycle? if so how can i do it without exceeding ? thanks

If you use HAL stop counting clocks :)

So firstly we have the original handler: interrupt entry takes about 12 clocks + FLASH wait states

```
void TIMx_IRQHandler(void)
{
  HAL_TIM_IRQHandler(&TimHandle);
}
```

Then we call HAL handler + min 3 clocks + waitstates as the pipeline is flushed.

Then we have HAL function - a lots of clock cycles:

```
void HAL_TIM_IRQHandler(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
  /* Capture compare 1 event */
  if(__HAL_TIM_GET_FLAG(htim, TIM_FLAG_CC1) != RESET)
  {
    if(__HAL_TIM_GET_IT_SOURCE(htim, TIM_IT_CC1) !=RESET)
    {
      {
        __HAL_TIM_CLEAR_IT(htim, TIM_IT_CC1);
        htim->Channel = HAL_TIM_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_1;

        /* Input capture event */
        if((htim->Instance->CCMR1 & TIM_CCMR1_CC1S) != 0x00U)
        {
          HAL_TIM_IC_CaptureCallback(htim);
        }
        /* Output compare event */
        else
        {
          HAL_TIM_OC_DelayElapsedCallback(htim);
          HAL_TIM_PWM_PulseFinishedCallback(htim);
        }
        htim->Channel = HAL_TIM_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_CLEARED;
      }
    }
  }
  /* Capture compare 2 event */
  if(__HAL_TIM_GET_FLAG(htim, TIM_FLAG_CC2) != RESET)
  {
    if(__HAL_TIM_GET_IT_SOURCE(htim, TIM_IT_CC2) !=RESET)
    {
      __HAL_TIM_CLEAR_IT(htim, TIM_IT_CC2);
      htim->Channel = HAL_TIM_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_2;
      /* Input capture event */
      if((htim->Instance->CCMR1 & TIM_CCMR1_CC2S) != 0x00U)
      {
        HAL_TIM_IC_CaptureCallback(htim);
      }
      /* Output compare event */
      else
      {
        HAL_TIM_OC_DelayElapsedCallback(htim);
        HAL_TIM_PWM_PulseFinishedCallback(htim);
      }
      htim->Channel = HAL_TIM_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_CLEARED;
    }
  }
  /* Capture compare 3 event */
  if(__HAL_TIM_GET_FLAG(htim, TIM_FLAG_CC3) != RESET)
  {
    if(__HAL_TIM_GET_IT_SOURCE(htim, TIM_IT_CC3) !=RESET)
    {
      __HAL_TIM_CLEAR_IT(htim, TIM_IT_CC3);
      htim->Channel = HAL_TIM_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_3;
      /* Input capture event */
      if((htim->Instance->CCMR2 & TIM_CCMR2_CC3S) != 0x00U)
      {
        HAL_TIM_IC_CaptureCallback(htim);
      }
      /* Output compare event */
      else
      {
        HAL_TIM_OC_DelayElapsedCallback(htim);
        HAL_TIM_PWM_PulseFinishedCallback(htim);
      }
      htim->Channel = HAL_TIM_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_CLEARED;
    }
  }
  /* Capture compare 4 event */
  if(__HAL_TIM_GET_FLAG(htim, TIM_FLAG_CC4) != RESET)
  {
    if(__HAL_TIM_GET_IT_SOURCE(htim, TIM_IT_CC4) !=RESET)
    {
      __HAL_TIM_CLEAR_IT(htim, TIM_IT_CC4);
      htim->Channel = HAL_TIM_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_4;
      /* Input capture event */
      if((htim->Instance->CCMR2 & TIM_CCMR2_CC4S) != 0x00U)
      {
        HAL_TIM_IC_CaptureCallback(htim);
      }
      /* Output compare event */
      else
      {
        HAL_TIM_OC_DelayElapsedCallback(htim);
        HAL_TIM_PWM_PulseFinishedCallback(htim);
      }
      htim->Channel = HAL_TIM_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_CLEARED;
    }
  }
  /* TIM Update event */
  if(__HAL_TIM_GET_FLAG(htim, TIM_FLAG_UPDATE) != RESET)
  {
    if(__HAL_TIM_GET_IT_SOURCE(htim, TIM_IT_UPDATE) !=RESET)
    {
      __HAL_TIM_CLEAR_IT(htim, TIM_IT_UPDATE);
      HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(htim);
    }
  }
  /* TIM Break input event */
  if(__HAL_TIM_GET_FLAG(htim, TIM_FLAG_BREAK) != RESET)
  {
    if(__HAL_TIM_GET_IT_SOURCE(htim, TIM_IT_BREAK) !=RESET)
    {
      __HAL_TIM_CLEAR_IT(htim, TIM_IT_BREAK);
      HAL_TIMEx_BreakCallback(htim);
    }
  }
  /* TIM Trigger detection event */
  if(__HAL_TIM_GET_FLAG(htim, TIM_FLAG_TRIGGER) != RESET)
  {
    if(__HAL_TIM_GET_IT_SOURCE(htim, TIM_IT_TRIGGER) !=RESET)
    {
      __HAL_TIM_CLEAR_IT(htim, TIM_IT_TRIGGER);
      HAL_TIM_TriggerCallback(htim);
    }
  }
  /* TIM commutation event */
  if(__HAL_TIM_GET_FLAG(htim, TIM_FLAG_COM) != RESET)
  {
    if(__HAL_TIM_GET_IT_SOURCE(htim, TIM_IT_COM) !=RESET)
    {
      __HAL_TIM_CLEAR_IT(htim, TIM_FLAG_COM);
      HAL_TIMEx_CommutationCallback(htim);
    }
  }
}
```

and eventually call to your function which execution will take between 8 and 15 clocks.

So if you have 25clocks in total you are a really lucky man.

Comment: Thank you for answering, i get it now that using HAL is not efficient at all for such a precise task where i have to deal with clock cycles, what do you think is a logical way of doing such a thing ?

Comment: i hope you have an idea

Comment: use bare registers without the HAL

Comment: https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/59/b9/ba/7f/11/af/43/d5/CD00171190.pdf/files/CD00171190.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00171190.pdf